# On the opencv path, haar cascade folder is not visible

Tags: opencv

Previously, I find the path of haar cascade using

> > > import cv2
> > >
> > > print(cv2.**file**)

/home/mohan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.

Recently, I installed ubuntu 19. 
Now the path showing is

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

where I didn't find any data folder. can anyone pls help me on this

Comment: What do you mean by ``any data folder```?

Comment: data is the name of the folder in which haarcascades available

Answer (score 0):

Have you built opencv from source?, if yes then you can access your haar cascades from path_to_your_downloaded_opencv_folder/data/haarcascades/. If you have done a pip install, then you will have to download it. Here is your link : https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

Comment: but clone option for download is not available. hw can i download that

Comment: You can either clone the whole repo or download the cascade files individually.